# ElasticSearch Security fearues license?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

I'm evaluating ES for our project use case. Once of the requirement is security. I have some questions regarding ES license and security features ?

1. Does basic license include security ?
2. If security enabled in basic ( free ) version does it include document fields level security ? if not what level free security stops ?

There are some confusing information regarding this hence i thought to post it here to get clear understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline answers:

*1. Does basic license include security ?*

**Yes, from ES 6.8 its included in basic free license but in basic license it's off by default using x-pack security config `xpack.security.enabled. it can be enabled.**

More info on [above setting in this official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-settings.html). Also please refer [Elastic blog on making security free](https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free), which has detailed information.

*2. If security enabled in basic ( free ) version does it include document fields level security? if not what level free security stops ?*

**Edit: As I looked into Elastic blog it seems the document level security is still a paid feature as from the same blog:**

> Note that our advanced security features — from single sign-on and
>   Active Directory/LDAP authentication to field- and document-level
>   security — remain paid features

More info on what is available in what subscription can be seen at [Elastic subscription matrix](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions)

Comment: ES includes security for free since v6.8 and v7.1, but 7.0 didn't have it: https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free

Comment: @Val, Yeah vaguely remember that and updated it as I looked into their blog to confirm that :)

Comment: Document/field-level security is not available in the Basic license, not even in Gold, only in Platinum: https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

Comment: @Val, I was confirming that only and just see my updated answer added the same details, anyway thanks for acting fast on this :)

Comment: @Val, now I am done with my answer, let me know if you have some comments, you type so fast(in a good manner) that sometime i don't even get a chance to update the answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213847/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-val).

Comment: @Val as you said document/field-level security not available in basic license. This is ES response to such request with basic license  ` {
                "type": "security_exception",
                "reason": "current license is non-compliant for [field and document level security]",
                "license.expired.feature": "field and document level security"
            }

Comment: @Viraj, yeah I also updated with the Elastic link mentioning this and subscription link which includes what all features available in a tier